# Troubles with Setters and Getters and Subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, setter, getter

I have been working on an assignment for days now and have been hitting my head against a wall. Basically were suppose to set up a superclass for Polygon like shapes and then encapsulate some data and use setters and getters to call that info into subclasses. I've been re-reading our book over and over and watching tons of tutorials online but its just not clicking for me. Here is an example of what I have so far for the Superclass:

```
public class Polygon {
   private double Sides;
   private double Length;
   private double Width;
   private double Height;

public double calcArea();
public double calcPerimeter();
}
```

The idea being that the subclasses will be able to define the parameters. 
I think this is correct, but I lose it when I start my subclasses, heres what I have for my first one right now, edited per suggestions:

```
  public class Triangle extends Polygon {

    public Triangle(){
    }

     public void Triangle (double Base, double Height) {
                this.Width = Base;
                this.Height = Height;
                this.Length = Length;
    }

    public double getWidth;
        return this.Width;
}
    public static setWidth(double Width){
        this.Width = 10;

}
    public double getHeight;
        return this.Height;

}
    public static setHeight(double Height){
        this.Height = 10;
    }
    public double getLength;
        return this.Length;
}
    public static setLength(double Width){
        this.Height = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public calcArea() {
        return 0.5 * Width * Height;
        }
    @Override
    public double calcPerimeter() {
        return Length + Length + Length;
    }
}
```

This is a huge work in progress so I know its sort of a mess, but I have errors thrown in pretty much every line and I don't know what part of the set/get I'm doing wrong. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated,  thanks.

Right now the errors I'm getting are: 
Lines 7/8/9: Width. Height, Length have private access in Polygon

Line 13: Illegal start of expression

And then lines 15/18/19/20/22/23/25/26/27/28/29/31/34/38/40: Class, interface, or enum expected.

Edit: It was suggested I removed the abstracts, so I did that.

Comment: Step 1 would be showing us the exact list of errors you get. We can't fix something if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `public void setWidth(double 10)` looks..... *interesting*, as does the line after it.

Comment: Line 1: Triangle is not abstract and does not override abstract method calcPerimeter() in Polygon

Line 7: Width has private access in Polygon
Line 8: Height has private access in Polygon
Line 12: Illegal start of type
Line 14: class, interface, or enum expected
Line 17: class, interface, or enum expected
Line 20: class, interface, or enum expected
Line 22: class, interface, or enum expected
Line 24: class, interface, or enum expected
Line 26: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Same with this `public double getWidth; return this.Width; }`

Comment: So... where exactly do you set `Length`?

Comment: I haven't gotten to that point yet, because I know the rest is wrong I figured I should start there before moving on

Comment: Fair enough;  however, you *really* shouldn't try to add all the errors as a comment.  If you have information like that which belongs in your question, you should [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find the way to do that, I'm new here, sorry. Went ahead and edited it up.

Comment: @Bucketman86 takes you all setters and getter to your superclass.

Comment: If you define Triangle as an abstract class then you can't create Triangle object. Abstract classes are not for creating objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should note that this is not the way you declare a function in Java.

```
  public double getLength;
        return this.Length;
}
```

but this should be

```
 public double getLength(){
        return this.Length;
}
```

Second thing , If you declare all classes abstract then you can't create object(by using `new` keyword).
btw here is a working version:

```
 public class Triangle extends Polygon {

    public Triangle(double base,double height,double length){
      super(base,height,length);  
     }


    @Override
    public double calcArea() {
        return 0.5 * this.getWidth() * this.getHeight();
        }
    @Override
    public double calcPerimeter() {
        return this.getLength() + this.getLength() + this.getLength();
    }


    //tests

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Triangle triangle = new Triangle(10,20,30);
        System.out.println(triangle.getWidth() + " width of a triangle");
        System.out.println(triangle.getHeight() + " height of a triangle");
        System.out.println(triangle.getLength() + " length of a triangle");

    }
}
```

If you want to give 4th parameter also to the super class(sides) then you can create one extra constructor with 4 paramters without deleting this one.

Here is your Polygon class:

```
public abstract class Polygon {
   private double Length;
   private double Width;
   private double Height;

public Polygon(double base, double height, double length) {
           this.Width = base;
           this.Height = height;
           this.Length = length;
}

public abstract double calcArea();
public abstract double calcPerimeter();


public double getWidth() {
    return this.Width;
}

public void setWidth(double Width){
    this.Width = Width;

}

public double getHeight() {
    return this.Height;

}
public void setHeight(double Height){
    this.Height = Height;
}
public double getLength() {
    return this.Length;
}

public void setLength(double length){
    this.Length = length;
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I forgot my parenthesis, thank you! and this makes much more sense then the reference material I was using.